# DotNet Core add dependecy in VS 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have 2 simple projects one is in DotNet Core(lets say CoreProject) and the other one is in .net 4.5.2 (let's say OldCode). I was able to reference the projects but when I call the OldCode from the CoreProject I encounter the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
HResult=0x80070002
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried to add System.Configuration to the project but I don't know exactly to which file I should add it. I do not have project.json. Only config files that I have are: launchSettings.json and appsettings.json. I add System.Configuration with nuGet because it's an older version.

Where I should put the reference so when I run the command dotnet restore to add the dependency to System.Configuration?

Comment: You can't use .NET 4.5.2 libraries in .NET Core. They must either be .NET Standard Library/PCL (which then can target netstandard1.0 to 1.6, which maps to certain feature sets of .NET >=4.5) or your ASP.NET Core project must target .NET >=4.5 too

Comment: @Tseng So if I have some code that can't be written in .net Core I won't be able to reference a project that is in 4.5.2?

Comment: Yes. That's why you have to put your code in NETStandard Library, this will make sure that your library only uses APIs which are available on all platforms (when you target netstandard1.x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, the .NET family looks something like this:

[image]
(Image is from [.NET Core, .NET Framework, Xamarin – The “WHAT and WHEN to use it”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/27/net-core-1-0-net-framework-xamarin-the-whatand-when-to-use-it/))

When you create a project targeting one of the frameworks at the top (e.g. .NET Core), you can't use that project against other frameworks (e.g. .NET Framework). `System.Configuration` is an asset that specifically targets .NET Framework, and it doesn't exist in .NET Core.

On the other hand, you can write code that is compatible with all the frameworks (within limits - see [compatibility chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library#net-platforms-support) to see how the versions map) by targeting .NET Standard, if your dependencies in turn target .NET Standard. This doesn't apply to `System.Configuration`, because that's .NET Framework-specific and does not target .NET Standard.

As an alternative, you can use the [.NET Core Configuration Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) (which, despite the name I'm using, actually targets .NET Standard and thus can be used in any framework). Or else you can use my very own [.NET Settings Framework](https://bitbucket.org/dandago/.net-settings-framework/wiki/Home) which is an abstraction that works with both the mature `System.Configuration`model (.NET Framework only) and the .NET Core configuration model (.NET Standard).